# How can I solve this librosa error in Python of a github project?

Tags: python, linux, package, librosa

I'm trying to run this GitHub project (https://github.com/filippogiruzzi/voice_activity_detection) on Linux. I've installed the requirements that appear on the README.md file. However, when it's about to run correctly. It appears the next error.

[image]

I run the next command line to make an inference:
python3 inference/inference.py --data_dir LibriSpeech/ --exported_model exported/ --smoothing

It has to be something that is related to librosa library.

Comment: Could you add the Audio file that caused this problem ( I think it's file 5142-33396-0045)? Also, where the code that you used to apply VAD over these files?

Comment: No, I couldn't. It doesn't require me the Audio file